# Exclude matches using regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, pcre

I have a few strings that have to be excluded from getting matched.

For example, a sample regex is

```
(?!(\bId=&quot;\d+&quot\b|\b4[78][0-9]{14}\b))(\bhello\b|\b49[0-9]{14}\b)
```

I'm using `(?!exclusion patterns)(inclusion patterns)` to recreate the exclusion of matches. In this, exclusion patterns are

```
(\bId=&quot;\d+&quot\b|\b4[78][0-9]{14}\b)
```

And inclusion patterns are

```
(\bhello\b|\b49[0-9]{14}\b)
```

However, it is showing a match on line 1 at https://regex101.com/r/iqbHPs/1 . I only expect a single match on line 4.

Why is it so?

Comment: Java regex is based on the ICU regex library, not PCRE. Where are you using the regex? How? Maybe all you need is `^(?!.*not this).*(take that)`? See `^(?!.*(?:\bId=&quot;\d+&quot\b|\b4[78][0-9]{14}\b)).*?(\bhello\b|\b49[0-9]{14}\b)` at https://regex101.com/r/iqbHPs/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can I use \B instead of \b in the exclusion patterns list to achieve my objective? This is just a sample regex. I'm using it to match sensitive data like credit card #s and exclude them from getting matched when they occur in patterns like Id=&quot;\d+&quot . Also, the relevant data can occur anywhere in the line. eg - https://regex101.com/r/7cwHKD/1 . here, it should not match *abc* on line 4.

Comment: `\B` has nothing to do with your question. If all you need is a single match when a string has no specific pattern in it, the solution above is what you need.

Comment: What about regex101.com/r/7cwHKD/1 . Here, it should not match abc on line 4.

Comment: You do not have to care what is matched, `abc` is not captured. You can always access the captured group in code. What is your code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew instead of accessing the captured group in code, is there a way to modify the regex such that i get only the number as an exact match on line 4 at regex101.com/r/7cwHKD/1 ?

Comment: Not the way you plan. https://regex101.com/r/7cwHKD/2

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to exclude any digit number within \bId=&quot;\d+&quot\b . You put a 16 digit number from getting matched in *(?!(?<=\bId=&quot;\d{16})&quot\b)* since I had one 16 digit inclusion pattern. When I try to use a quantifier {12,19} (since cc #s can be b/w 12 and 19 digits), i get an error - *A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width*. How can I place a range of digits in *(?!(?<=\bId=&quot;\d{16})&quot\b)* . Hope I was clear in my explanation.

Comment: No, it is fine in Java, see https://regex101.com/r/7cwHKD/3. Just always use the right regex engine option when testing regexps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have this regex *<[id]val>-?[0-9]+\.([0-9]+)?</[id]val>* . Dont want to match any of the numbers in this. How can I go about doing it in the context of excluding the pattern from getting matched? I came up with https://regex101.com/r/aicSoc/1 and it matches the numbers after . which I dont want. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=<[id]val>-?[0-9]{12,19})\.(?=[0-9]{0,19}</[id]val>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nAwHU7/1).

- `(?<=<[id]val>-?[0-9]{12,19})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `<`, `i` or `d`, `val>`, and optional `-`, and then 12 to 19 digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=[0-9]{0,19}</[id]val>)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `[0-9]{0,19}` - zero to 19 digits
  - `</[id]val>` - `</`, `i` or `d` and then `val`.